# Linq Enity Framework, select from collection within IQueryable navigation property

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

[image]

If you look at the above I basically am trying to write a query off of the main table.

For the purposes of conserving space, I only selected one field from the above table `Id` but I need the whole table.

Here's my crude objective in the SQL / linq hybrid format. I've been playing with this in linq forever using `.Contains`, `SelectMany`, `.Any` and I can't find the magic syntax.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Crude objective:

```
select * 
from table 
where BehaviourResourceAgeLevels.AgeLevelId = 1
```

**EDIT**
Thanks @Matt
Your solution helped me refine my query:

```
                        var ageLevels = unitOfWork.AgeLevels.AsQueryable().SelectMany(x => x.BehaviourResources)
                            .Where(x => x.Id == resourceId).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your question exactly, would share your c# code and explain on it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SelectMany`

```
table.SelectMany(x=> x.BehaviourResourceAgeLevels).Where(x=> x.AgeLevelId == 1)
```

`SelectMany` picks out all like properties from a collection and stuffs them into a single collection you can then filter further.

Comment: Thanks Matt!  This got me over hurdle one.  I updated my original question to expand on my ultimate goal.  Which is selecting a entity set field based on the value you helped me select.  Selecting just the entity set field is now where I'm stuck.  Any help is appreciated, thx again

Comment: Sorry, just saw this - if you want to select just BehaviorLevel for instance, you would just append .Select(x=>x.BehaviorLevel)